# Getting NMEA DATA in android

Tags: java, android, nmea

The current issue that I'm getting is that the OnNmeaListener is not returning the correct data from the NMEA using the GpsStatus.Listener therefore  I tried the GNSS Status for the peace of mind, it ended up returning gibberish data , so I had to revert back to GpsStatus Listener. I also prior to using OnNmeaListener tried GpsStatus.NmeaListner and when used tried to add it to the GpsStatus Listener it would show up as an error and suggested that i typecast it  to OnNmeaListener, when this is done and the app is built and all and then executed from the app, it would crash and then not work at all, and this is why i shifted to OnNmeaListener in the first place. Now to its credit  the OnNmeaListener works just fine and doesn't crash at all, but the data it gives out is not at all accurate, I thought maybe this might have to be some sort of fault/error on the device side, I then proceeded to test it on two devices with different API levels of 25 and 28, On the the 25 Level device it just did not give half of the data whereas on the 28 level device the data is full but not accurate and correct.

This is the method that I'm currently using:

```
OnNmeaMessageListener nmeaMessageListener = new OnNmeaMessageListener () {
    @Override
    public void onNmeaMessage(String nmea , long timestamp) {
        if (trackStarted == true && trackPaused == false) {
            if (nmea.startsWith ( "$GPGGA" ) || nmea.startsWith ( "$GPRMC" )) {
                //Log.d("TrackManagerService","NMEA:" + nmea);
                try {
                    // out.write(nmea.getBytes());

                    if (continuesMode) {
                        dataOut.write ( nmea.getBytes () );
                        bufferedNMEALines++;
                        if (bufferedNMEALines >= 10) {
                            flushContinuesTrack ();
                            //dataOut.reset();
                            bufferedNMEALines = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        outCompressed.write ( nmea.getBytes () );
                    }

                    // Log.d("TrackManagerService","NMEA:" + nmea);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

                if (nmea.startsWith ( "$GPGGA" )) {
                    String[] nmeaSplit = nmea.split ( "," );
                    if (nmeaSplit.length > 10) {
                        if (nmeaSplit[9].length () > 0) {
                            try {
                                mslAltitude = Float.parseFloat ( nmeaSplit[9] );
                            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                mslAltitude = 0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            mslAltitude = 0.0f;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //if (markStarted && hasFix() && nmea.startsWith("$GPGGA")) {
            if (markStarted && hasFix () && nmea.startsWith ( "$GPRMC" )) {
                markProgress++;
                trackListener.onMarkProgress ( markProgress );
                if (markProgress >= markMax) {
                    stopMark ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And this is the output it gives when called:

```
$Start,082719,260220;
$GPGGA,082721.42,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*44
$GPRMC,082721.42,V,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0.000,0.000,260220,E,N*01
$GPGGA,082722.41,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*44
$GPRMC,082722.41,V,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0.000,0.000,260220,E,N*01
$End,082802,260220;
$Start,082804,260220;
$GPGGA,082837.42,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*4C
$GPRMC,082837.42,V,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0.000,0.000,260220,E,N*09
$GPGGA,082838.42,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*43
$GPGGA,082840.42,2654.2979,N,08056.6065,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*4C
$End,082841,260220;
$Start,082921,260220;
$GPGGA,082923.40,2654.2982,N,08056.6059,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*41
$GPRMC,082923.40,V,2654.2982,N,08056.6059,E,0.000,0.000,260220,E,N*04
$GPGGA,082924.40,2654.2982,N,08056.6059,E,0,100.000,0.000,M,M,0,*46
$GPRMC,082945.40,V,2654.2982,N,08056.6059,E,0.000,0.000,260220,E,N*04
$End,082945,260220;
```

And this is the output when called using GNSS listener:

> $Start,080450,260220;������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

Any Sort of way to make this works?

**[EDIT]**

This is the response from an iOS device, which was accepted by the sever:

```
$Start,150403,250220;
$GPGGA,150403.69,2654.29986954,N,8056.60312653,E,1,00,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0000*42;
$GPRMC,150743.99,A,2654.29986954,N,8056.60260391,E,0.0,0.0,250220,0.0,E,A*5;
$GPRMC,150844.26,A,2654.29986954,N,8056.60260391,E,0.0,0.0,250220,0.0,E,A*9;

$GPRMC,150937.91,A,2654.30012894,N,8056.60312653,E,0.0,0.0,250220,0.0,E,A*e;
$GPGGA,150945.04,2654.30429840,N,8056.60781097,E,1,00,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0000*42;
$GPRMC,150952.01,A,2654.29921722,N,8056.60364532,E,0.0,0.0,250220,0.0,E,A*2;
$End,150953,250220;
$GPGGA,150953.00,2654.29921722,N,8056.60364532,E,1,00,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0000*42;
$GPRMC,150953.00,A,2654.29921722,N,8056.60364532,E,0.0,0.0,250220,0.0,E,A*2;
```

Now, I DO NOT have the faintest idea how this works on an iOS device,*(a Senior of mine worked on that and gave me this data)* but somehow it worked on that and when the same logic was implemented on Android and the data was uploaded to the server it wouldn't accept it, whereas when the iOS data was manipulated in any sort of way ( removing lines, addlines, removing semi-colons, commas,etc.) it would somehow still work.

Comment: `And this is the output it gives when called:` That looks nice to me. Can you post another block to show us how it should look like according to you?

Comment: Hey @blackapps, I just updated the question, and to be clear, I don't say that the data is  wrong , I said it might not be accurate or something, for it not to uploaded.

Comment: They look about the same. But what is that M? I think it should not not be too difficult to find out why the server is accepting the one and refusing the other. You could do a test where you let Android app send that ios block.

Comment: I dont know whats up with that **M** ,and yes i did try to send the iOS data and it did work.Now i can't find why that works for that but not for the data generated by android, and i did test it out on multiple devices of different manufacturers.

Comment: What is in the servers logs? Or what message do you get if the server refuses? The server should tell why.

Comment: When the file is not correct irt gives out an error :  `{"result":"error","msgId":5}` and that's it. Whereas when the iOS file is uploaded it gives the desired data in its response

Comment: Talk with the server programmer to get better messages and logs. The lazy one...